A first order linear differential question that may have only the trivial solution $y = 0$.
Below is a problem I made up. I expected the differential equation to have
a unique non-trivial solution. However, it did  not. Is my solution wrong?
Problem:
Solve the following differential equation:
$$ \dfrac{dy}{dx} + xy = 0 $$
with the following initial condition: $y(0) = 0$.
Answer:
This is a first order linear differential equation.
\begin{align*}
I &= e ^{  \int x \,\, dx } \\
I &= e^{ \dfrac{ x^2} {2} } \\
e^{ \dfrac{ x^2} {2} } \dfrac{dy}{dx} + x e^{ \dfrac{ x^2} {2} } y &= 0 \\
{\large D} \left( e^{ \dfrac{ x^2} {2} } y \right) &= \int 0 \,\, dx \\
e^{ \dfrac{ x^2} {2} } y &= C \\
y &= C e^{ -\dfrac{ x^2} {2} }
\end{align*}
Now I try to find $C$.
\begin{align*}
y(0) &= 0 = Ce^{-0} \\
Ce^{-0} &= 0 \\
C &= 0 \\
\end{align*}
Hence we have the solution:
$$ y = 0  $$

Your solution is correct.

Why did you "expect the differential equation to have a unique non-trivial solution? You should rather expect it to have a unique solution, and note immediately (without any calculation) that $y=0$ is a solution (hence is this unique solution).

@AnneBauval The reason I expected a unique non-trivia solution is that all the first order differential equations that I  have solved in the past did have non-trivial solutions.

A linear first order differential equation with initial condition always has a unique solution (which may happen to be $0$).

Echoing @AnneBauval's first comment...

The answer is correct. It is true that a first order differential equation with initial conditions will always have a unique solution. However, that solution  might be the trivial solution $y = 0$. In  this case, the solution is $y = 0$.
The given differential equation is separable and can be solved that way.
